# Return "GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync" only in development mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, development-environment, production-environment

I have ResetPassword method that creates a token using GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync. I test my API using Postman and I want it to return the token when in development mode
But in production environment, I just want to send 200 OK and not return a token.

How can I inject environment dependency in such a case?

Answer (score 0):

Inject [IWebHostEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostenvironment?view=aspnetcore-3.1) into the Controller /PageModel constructor, and judge the environment mode. You could refer to the below example

```
 public class StudentsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
    public StudentsController(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        if(_env.EnvironmentName.Equals("Development"))
        {
            // creates a token using GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync
        }

        else if(_env.EnvironmentName.Equals("Production "))
        {
            //send 200 OK
        }
    }
}
```